# Expanding RAID6 with LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, raid6

My question is a bit broader than the question title, but here is my situation: I have [Synology Hybrid Raid (SHR)](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID%3F) built on 2 x 2TB drives. I want to migrate to a software-RAID on a homegrown linux machine. My current plan is backup the SHR remotely, setup a RAID6 with LVM using 3 x 2TB drives, and then restore the backed-up directories to the new RAID.

In the future, if I want to add more drives, is it possible to dynamically expand the RAID6? Are there any good articles explaining the relationship between RAID6 and LVM? This machine will be for my own person use and limited web traffic, so drive fault tolerance is more important to me than speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the RAID like this:

```
lvcreate --type raid6 --stripes 1 -L 1T --name MyRaidLV MyVG
```

`--stripes 1` is the number of disks aside from RAID6's two redundancy disks, `-L 1T` is the visible size of the raid array.  Then you can expand the raid with `lvextend -L +1T`, or add disks with

```
vgextend MyVG $NewDiskOrPartition
lvconvert --stripes 2 MyVG/MyRaidLV
```

The relationship between LVM and mdraid is basically that the kernel side is mdraid, and the management commands are LVM. The relevant commands are described [in this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/raid_volumes.html) and in man pages.

Comment: What would be the reason to not just use mdadm to create/expand/manage the RAID?

Comment: One good reason to use LVM in combination with md RAID is to be able to use LVM cache devices. For an example, see https://current.workingdirectory.net/posts/2022/lvm-cache/